# Implementing In App Purchases in IOS Widget

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, widget, in-app-purchase

I'm currently stuck trying to implement in app purchases within my IOS Widget.  My widget works, the in-app purchase works, and the app works for the baseline functions.

I am unable to make the purchases available within the **widget**. My current strategy is to use if else statements to turn change with parts of code to point to.

Could anyone tell me how to implement in app purchases within my Widget?

Here is my code:

```
code 



import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI



struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.QuotePackage")
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        _ = Quote.self
    
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "premiumQuotes") == true {
            // remove adds
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quoteDetails: QuoteProvider.random())
            
        } else {
            return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quoteDetails: QuoteProvider2.random2())
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.QuotePackage")
  public typealias Entry = SimpleEntry

    public func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "premiumQuotes") == true {
            // remove adds
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quoteDetails: QuoteProvider.random())
            
        } else {
            
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), quoteDetails: QuoteProvider2.random2())
        }
    completion(entry)
  }

    
    public func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

    // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
    let currentDate = Date()
    for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
      let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "premiumQuotes") == true {
            // remove adds
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, quoteDetails: QuoteProvider.random())
        } else {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, quoteDetails: QuoteProvider2.random2())
        }
      entries.append(entry)
    }

    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
  }
}


struct Quote_WidgetEntryView: View {
  var entry: Provider.Entry

  var body: some View {
      QuoteWidgetEntryView(quoteDetails: entry.quoteDetails)
  }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
  public let date: Date
  public let quoteDetails: QuoteDetails
}

struct PlaceholderView : View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Inspo")
  }
}

struct QuoteWidgetEntryView : View {
    
    let quoteDetails: QuoteDetails
  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            
            VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
                Text("\"\(quoteDetails.texts)\"")
                    .font(Font.custom("Georgia", size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(5)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                Text("\(quoteDetails.authors)")
                    .font(Font.custom("Georgia", size: 15))
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
           
                
        }
    }
}




@main
struct Quote2_Widget: Widget {
  private let kind: String = "Quote2_Widget"

  public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
      
      if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "premiumQuotes") == true {
          // remove adds
      StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
          QuoteWidgetEntryView(quoteDetails: QuoteProvider.random())
          
      } else {
          StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
              QuoteWidgetEntryView(quoteDetails: QuoteProvider.random())
      }
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("Inspo")
    .description("Add Inspo Quotes to your homescreen.")
    .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
  }
}
}
struct QuoteWidgetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
      QuoteWidgetEntryView(quoteDetails: QuoteProvider.random())
      .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. While a widget can a button/ tappable area there is no way to get responses and such. Widgets don't observe anything. When a purchase is made in the app you can reload the timelines to get the widget to refresh but the entry itself is `static` meaning it won't change on its own.

Comment: thanks.. that takes me back to the drawing board,

Comment: try [Apple's code along](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie) you can guide the user to the purchase screen in your app with a deep link with a tappable area. Then you can communicate with the widget using app group to load the timelines according to a shared UserDefault or other type of storage.